# jQuery Mobile unable to refresh browser

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, refresh

I am working on my first jQuery Mobile web application.  It is a multi-page application all in one html file.  The pages all exist, at load time, but the content in those pages are created dynamically.

The main page that is loaded when the html page is loaded is called `#mapWindow`.  Another page is called `#formWindow` and is dynamically populated with form elements based on a point selected on the map in `#mapWindow`.

If I am currently looking at `#formWindow` my url is: `http://my/url.html#formWindow`.  If I hit the refresh button on my browser (Chrome), I just get a spinning wheel in my browser and the console says `"Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: :nth-child"` in `"jquery-1.9.0.min.js"`.

I did some testing using the `window.onbeforeunload` and `window.onunload` events and this error occurs after the page has been unloaded.  With further testing, I placed a breakpoint on the very first line of Javascript in my html page, which is before the jQuery `.js` files are loaded.  The error I have seen occurs before the breakpoint.  In fact, the breakpoint doesn't even get hit because of the error.

I have no clues what is happening here, or when it is happening.  I have seen this error message once before in a different situation when I was trying to destroy a `navbar` before it had any items added to it.  I was able to fix that by checking for items before calling `$("[data-role='navbar']").navbar("destroy")`.

Comment: When you refresh, it should reload `url.html` and show `#mapWindow`. What version of jQM is used? can you share the code of how you inject `#formWindow` dynamically?

Comment: @Omar - I am using jQuery Mobile v1.3.0.  When I refresh from `#formWindow`, my url remains as `url.html#formWindow`.  I do not inject `#formWindow` dynamically.  The page is defined in my original html.  I simply use javascript to append form elements inside a div with `data-role="content"` that is nested inside `#formWindow`.

Comment: I dont think that `url.html#formWindow` while refreshing causes that error. Try creating two pages with simple data and then refresh when second page is active, and see if you get the same error.